# Open multiple files with specific names

Tags: c#, file, document

I'm writing a program to calculate the Flesch score. I want to import multiple files, analyze them, then output the soloution in the console. How can I only read .txt files with the the start name "testcase" ? F.e. "testcase_text1.txt".

Comment: have you tried something?

Comment: No really clue about that stuff. Maybe something like this: `string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"S:\work\Flesch_Reading_Ease\", "testcase*");`

Comment: What part of your question are you having trouble with? What code do you have and where are you stuck?

Comment: You want to open multiple .txt files at a time, do you? Have you searched for solutions or have you tried your own?

Comment: I searched for a solution but didn't really get it.

Answer (score 1):

you could get all the file names in an array by doing this

```
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(source_folder, "testcase*.txt");
```

Then just access any file you want and process it.
You could use `EnumerateFiles` instead of `GetFiles` and start processing on a file as soon as it is fetched.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Linq* with `Directory.EnumerateFiles` to get initial files to proceed:

```
  var source = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(@"C:\MyFiles", "testcase*.txt")
    .Select(file => new {
       Name = Path.GetFileName(file),
       Score = FleschKincaidScore(file) //TODO: implement FleschKincaidScore 
     })
    .OrderBy(item => item.Score) // let's sort the records
    .ThenBy(item => item.Name)
    .Select(item => String.Format("File {0} has score {1}", item.Name, item.Score));

  // Final report
  Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, source));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("testcase_text" + i + ".txt");
    // process the file...
}
```